# MaterializeCSS Component Missing Something Critical

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I've been struggling to get MaterializeCSS elements to work properly in my project.  None of the JS functions work and I'm not sure why.

This is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfsbx6cg/1/) that doesn't work.

As far as I can tell, it's an exact replica of [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/juands/z512cb7f/3/) that does.  So what's missing?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('#modal1').on('click', function() {
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn view" data-target="modal1">View Scores</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is**: `materialize` needs `jquery` so you need to import jquery first before `materialize.js`

[image]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('#modal1').on('click', function() {
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn view" data-target="modal1">View Scores</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```